# Why consider non-farm payrolls?

Tags: labor-economics, unemployment, usa

Why does the US consider non-farm payrolls when looking at employment levels? What are the reasons for not including farms? Are the workers too transitive, does it not contribute in a certain way to economy which is undesirable to measure? Other countries seem to have similar ways to measure employment levels which suggests farms payrolls are problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a [blog post](http://blog.trading212.com/why-non-farm-payrolls-influence-the-dollar-and-stock-markets-so-much/) aiming to answer your question.

Also, I am not sure if you mean the NFP is problematic or if general payroll estimations are problematic. I would say the later is, and the blog post highlights some reasons why.

Comment: Partially answered my question. 1) The farming industry "skews the overall data due to seasonality". Why dont we exclude the tourism industry as well? 2) "excluding those in the farming industry (for reasons probably linked to the picture above)" I cannot see what the reason is?

Comment: @sandstone  I think your original post did not cover your questions outlined in (1). And here is another link that provides the information that should have been linked in the picture: http://econblog.aplia.com/2009/05/why-do-monthly-job-loss-estimates.html, and should answer (2). If you would like to post a new question for (1), feel free, and I will answer it.